# Maintain directory hierarchy when converting from XSD to JAVA Class?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jsonschema

I have a set of XSD Schemas , that are present in a directory structure . I am using JAXB to convert it into Java Classes . Now when converting it it breaks the schema into several classes and puts them into the default package. I can override the default package but i would like to maintain the same directory structure of the XSD. 
[image: XSD Schema]
Does this mean i will have to convert each XSD one at a time by hand. Also , since it is breaking the single XSD into multiple classes , it will make it tough for me to convert these classes into JSON schema . So ideally i would like each XSD to convert to a single class . So, i will put in simpler words my questions

1. How do i maintain the directory structure ?
2. How do i ensure that each XSD corresponds to a single java class?
3. Since myultimate goal is to convert the xsd to JSON Schema , am I doing it all wrong ?
4. should i take a different approach like converting XSD to JSON and
   then may be    manipulating it to become JSON Schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using proper namespace in XSDs, it will create the class structure accordingly.
if namespace is `http://www.company.com/XML/schema/product1` then the classes would be generated in `com.company.xml.schema.product1.xxxx`