# Convert XSD to JSON Schema

Tags: json, xsd, xsd-validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My application support XML and JSON content type. I have XSD to validate XML content. I want to convert XSD to create a JSON Schema. Can I achieve this functionality in using C# ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Json schema from XML schema (XSD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922026/generate-json-schema-from-xml-schema-xsd)

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial .NET library [XsdToJsonSchema](https://nciphers.com/xsdtojson/) that converts from XSD to JSON schema that seems to be close to what you are looking for. A code snippet from its page:

```
string xsd = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xsd"); 
string jsonSchema = XsdToJsonSchema.XsdToJsonSchemaConverter.ConvertXsdToJsonSchema(xsd);
```